# Does 'Inverse Kinematics' override other bone constraints?

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

Rig is for a quadruped, I have IK applied at second bone, but I want to place a limit on the to the toes, so that they can't go below 0 on the Z axis. Selecting  the Limit Location bone constraint doesn't appear to be honored when striking a pose.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the issue. My active 'Copy Location' constraint was overriding my "Limit Location" constraint. Priority in the constraints appears to flow up to down.

Comment: Yes, the upper constraints or modifiers have the first priority. It's also explained here somewhere in this tutorial that explains everything about IK. It could be related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gq7K1mX4pRI